# In HIghcharts - Legend, Can we able to add just border bottom?

Tags: highcharts

I have tried,borderWidth, borderColor. But did not able to find to just add border bottom to single item in legend.

Thanks in advance..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Set [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.useHTML) and then use HTML tags with CSS in [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter).

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to underline an item you can use labelFormatter like this:(http://jsfiddle.net/L4D5U/)

```
legend: {
    labelFormatter: function() {
        return '<div style="text-decoration: underline">'+this.name+'</div>' ;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a bottom border to legend main container <g class="highcharts-legend"  ?